# MacOS Big Sur `/etc/hosts/` not working properly

Tags: macos, localhost, hosts

I am trying to add `localhost.com` & `admin.localhost.com` as hosts for localhost. I tried everything, from any thinkable order between these, to flushing cache (`dscacheutil -flushcache`), killing `mDNSResponder`, using root user, enabling auto proxy discovery.

This is my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost

127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.com
127.0.0.1 localhost admin.localhost.com

::1             localhost
```

I also tried debugging using:

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name admin.localhost.com
----- and got:
name: localhost
alias: admin.localhost.com
ip_address: 127.0.0.1
```

But whenever I try to access `admin.localhost.com` I get `This site can’t be reached`. I also restarted my laptop multiple times. The app I try to open is a Rails app and opening it with `localhost:3000` works, but that's not what I need.

Comment: If `dscacheutil` sees the entry, that means the macOS resolver is seeing it. Are you using a browser that bypasses the macOS system resolver or something like that?

Comment: I am using just chrome & safari